# why php returns null instead of value passed from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I just started to learn php and want to GET/POST some data. I can send data from php to javascript, but not other way around, there is just null. What am i doing wrong?

JS:

```
const postData = async (data) => {
    try {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };
        fetch('/server.php', requestOptions)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
postData({ test: 'testData' });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $myObj->name = "John";
    $myObj->age = 30;
    $myObj->test = $_POST['test'];

    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

    echo($myJSON);
?>
```

The result is {name: 'John', age: 30, test: null}

I can see data from php which is already good for me, but i want to send there data too, so i can later work with real database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data in PHP correctly from JS you need to use `file_get_contents("php://input")`.
To get data in JS correctly from a PHP response, set the headers `application/json` in PHP and then `echo json_encode($myObj...`.

```
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
$decoded = [];
if ($contentType === "application/json" || $contentType === "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {
    $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $decoded = json_decode($content, true);
}else{
    $decoded = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->test = $decoded['test'];

header("ContentType: application/json");
echo json_encode($myObj, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

Answer (score 2):

The PHP `$_POST` variable holds the data parsed by PHP for [`POST` requests with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encoded content](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

But your JS code actually sends the data encoded as `application/json` in the body. This is not automatically picked up by PHP and you need to manually parse the body:

```php
<?php

$bodyContent = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonContent = json_decode($bodyContent, true);
$testValue = $jsonContent['test'];

echo $testValue;
```

Comment: this gives me error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'e', "testData" is not valid JSON